# javafx Check if an object exists in scene

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to both java and javafx. How can I check if any object like Rectangle or Button exists in the Stack Pane or in the scene ? Tried searching in google but couldn't find anything related to the same.

Comment: Provide some code, show us what you have tried so far . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if a `Node` (could be `Button`, `Rectangle` or any other UI node) is a direct child of another node (parent assumed, `StackPane` in your question) you can do the following:

```
stackPane = ...
if (stackPane.getChildren().contains(node)) {
    // node is a direct child of stackPane
}
```

Alternatively, you can call `node.getParent()` to obtain a reference to the parent node, if there is one.

Finally, by calling `node.getScene() != null` you can check if a node is part of a scene.

For full documentation refer to [JavaFX API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getParent--).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are also searching for a way to check if a certain [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) is a **direct or indirect child** of another [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) or [`Scene`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html).

---

Following a method that checks if a certain [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) is a direct or indirect child of another [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html). For that, it traverses the parent, the grandparent, and so on, and checks if it encounters the parent in question:

```
public static boolean isChildOf(Node nodeInQuestion, Node parentInQuestion) {
    Node cur = nodeInQuestion.getParent();
    while (cur != null) {
        if (cur == parentInQuestion) {
            return true;
        }
        cur = cur.getParent();
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

To check if a given [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) is the root or an indirect child of a [`Scene`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html), we can use a similar approach. This method traverses the node's parent chain up to the node's root and then compares the node's root to the scene's root (which is true if the node in question is part of the scene):

```
public static boolean isChildOf(Node nodeInQuestion, Scene sceneInQuestion) {
    Node rootOfNode = nodeInQuestion;
    while (rootOfNode.getParent() != null) {
        rootOfNode = rootOfNode.getParent();
    }
    return sceneInQuestion.getRoot() == rootOfNode;
}
```